# Read SD card on ATMEGA328 from ESP826

Tags: esp8266, wifi, sd-card, arduino-uno-wifi

I have a ATMEGA328 with ESP826 (like this http://arduinolearning.com/hardware/atmega328-esp8266-arduino-board.php) and can successfully send information from the ATMEGA328 to the ESP826 via serial.
I can also record information from the ATMEGA328 to SD card.
What I would like to do is read data from the SD card with the ESP826 so I can upload it to a server..

When I try to connect directly:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  if (!SD.begin(10)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }

  myFile = SD.open("/");

  printDirectory(myFile, 0);

  Serial.println("done!");
  
}

void loop(){
}


void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs) {
  while (true) {

    File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
    if (! entry) {
      // no more files
      break;
    }
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
      Serial.print('\t');
    }
    Serial.print(entry.name());
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
      Serial.println("/");
      printDirectory(entry, numTabs + 1);
    } else {
      // files have sizes, directories do not
      Serial.print("\t\t");
      Serial.println(entry.size(), DEC);
    }
    entry.close();
  }
}
```

It doesn't find the card. This is regardless of whether I have pins 1&2 ON or not.

Is there any way to write to the SD card using the ATMEGA328 and read that from the ESP826 (to send the files to the cloud)?

Comment: you can't. SPI pins of the esp8266 are not accessible on Uno+WiFi. you can't wire an SD card to the esp8266.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There's no connection between the ESP8266 and the SD card.

However you can program the ATMega328 to read the SD card then send that data to the ESP8266 for forwarding to the internet.

Comment: Thanks! What's the best way to send data from the ATMega to the ESP8266? The file on the SD card will be a sound file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider something like nodeMCU?
Is there a reason why you using such a complicated board?
This would enable you to connect your SD card reader directly to nodeMCU, which can read the data  from same inputs as atmega328 (watch for voltage differences) including the sensors which has the capability of uploading data to the cloud without the need of additional MCU, while making debugging far easier.

I know that I am going to get dislikes here, but it looks to me like one of those cases when you connect two things that would work better of alone, making something does doesn't do either ones job very well.
Maybe you can get a refund...
If not contact your card issuer for "Cardholder not present" claim that bot VISA and Master card have.

Is there any reason why wouldn't standard nodeMCU be enough for your project? (probably superior)

If its not enough:

If you connect node-mcu (5-15 Eur/Pounds/Dolars) and a nano (About half of the price) on a breadboard and connect them together via (software) serial pin, (using jumper cables and resistive divider), you can program them without messing with pointless dip switches  and learn something usefull for future projects. latter you can replace nano for 3V3 pro miny to remove even the divider.
There is this absurd idea from Arduino core team developers of using superiour Esp32 MCU as a secondary tool to inferiour ATMEGA328, while logically you should do the opposite.
This is amplified by the fact that I would personaly consider Esp8266 core arduino libraries superior to those made for atmel...
You might even find that the 2-3MB FS you can create on ModeMCU might be enough without the need of SD card.

I had a quick look through the site and a combination defaulting to http and nonstandard hardware, combined with low standard of explanation, **But what I find really imoral is harvesting excessive number of domain names on a similar subject** which could have been used for other projects makes me think if these tutorials are designed to increase the sales of badly designed boards... I would recommend you to change the tutorial source...

Comment: point taken , comment deleted

Comment: Can you tell me what this statement has to do with the question: "BUT EVEN WORSE STEALING EXCESSIVE NUMBER OF DOMAIN NAMES"? Using all capital letters, with a bold and italic font, is NOT going to send the message you think it will to the community.

Comment: I think pointing out the immoral action of the website designers, is relevant in pointing as additional reasons to point asker towards better tutorial, or source for board. I have rephrased, the sentence (not sure how did caps happened)

Comment: So now, you change the irrelevant text to this "But what I find really imoral is harvesting excessive number of domain names on a similar subject domain names" with a bold font.Can you tell me how that statement applies to the OP's question?

Comment: I am unable to explain you mine reasoning any better then in mine previous comment. maybe once I think how to rephrase explanation for mine reasoning. Otherwise we may have to differ in opinion and I will get mine expected down-vote. I accept that you are better at programming then me, just disagree with you on this point. Good night